# How to query and sum data with the same name, but still get the name

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have table 'sales_revenue', it looks like this:

```
product_name     |   revenue   | 
  pen            |      20     |   
  pen            |      40     |   
  bottle         |      50     |  
  bottle         |      50     |  
  green pen      |      20     |
```

my query in codeigniter is like this:

```
$data['row'] = $this->db->group_by('product_name')- 
>order_by('revenue','DESC')->select_sum('revenue')- 
>get('sales_revenue')->result();
```

It result only the sum of the revenue, but my goal is to get the total revenue of each product and also the product name as well. Any sugestion how to do this?

Comment: Is your desired output to have a field (column) with the per-item revenue? (I.e. `revenue * Quantity`), or to have a record returned with the sum of the revenue column? (I.e. `... green pen | 20 | 1; total | 180 | -`), or to have a record returned with the sumproduct of the revenue column? (I.e. `... green pen | 20 | 1; total | 220 | -`)

Comment: I have edited the table, the goal of my query is to return the total revenue for each product and also the name of the product. I use the result to create a bar chart by using product name as the category or the x-axis and the total revenue as the y-axis

Comment: if you found your own answer, please don't add it in the question, but write a proper answer (you need +15 reputation, which you have). You can even accept your own answer, read here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: okay, I dont know about that. I have edited my question

Answer (score 0):

I haven´t test it, but I think you can do the following

```
$data['row'] = $this->db->group_by('product_name')
    ->order_by('revenue','DESC')
    ->select('SUM(revenue), product_name')
    ->get('sales_revenue')->result();
```

or simply:

```
$data['row'] = $this->db->query('SELECT SUM(revenue), product_name FROM sales_revenue GROUP BY product_name ORDER BY revenue DESC')
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you for your response, I have tried it actually and it always return this kind of message: Expression #1 of ORDER BY clause is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'datamart_kf.sales_revenue.revenue' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Answer (score 0):

Simply use

```
$data['row'] = $this->db->query('SELECT product_name,SUM(revenue) AS revenue FROM sales_revenue GROUP BY product_name ORDER BY product_name DESC')
```

If you want to sort it for revenue, use

```
ORDER BY SUM(revenue) ASC
```

Comment: Thnk you for your response, but finnaly I got the right query:       $data['row'] = $this->db->group_by('product_name')->order_by('revenue','DESC')->select_sum('revenue')->select('product_name')->get('sales_revenue')->result();

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about codeigniter, but in standard SQL you could do it with an alias.

```sql
SELECT product_name, revenue, (SELECT sum(revenue) FROM sales_revenue) as total_revenue FROM sales_revenue GROUP BY product_name ORDER BY revenue DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

I found my own answer to this problem:

```
 $data['row'] = $this->db ->group_by('product_name')
                          ->order_by('revenue','DESC')
                          ->select_sum('revenue')
                          ->select('product_name')
                          ->get('sales_revenue')
                          ->result();
```